# Not getting the link After API function while uploading a document on url

Tags: python, sharepoint, python-requests, office365api

I am trying to upload a spreadsheet on Sharepoint for which I am using REST API function.

The code that I am using for generating the url as well as uploading the file is-

```
import sys
import requests, os
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

sharePointUrl = 'https://Sharepoint.asr.ith.itl.com/Skt/patchboard'
folderUrl = '/Documents/Patch_automation_work_area'
fileName='/abc/asc/roj/skx/skx_val/rsingh/Patch/Excel.xlsm'

#Setting up the url for requesting a file upload
requestUrl = sharePointUrl + '/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(\'' + folderUrl + '\')/Files/addas(url=\'' + fileName + '\',overwrite=true)'
print(requestUrl)
```

When printing the URL generated getting the output as-

> https://Sharepoint.asr.ith.itl.com/Skt/patchboard/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Documents/Patch_automation_work_area')/Files/addas(url='/abc/asc/roj/skx/skx_val/rsingh/Patch/Excel.xlsm',overwrite=true)

So the complete URL is not generated for uploading the file and it is showing 404 error when accessing the link using requests module in python. Can somebody please help me why I am getting this erroe and how to generate link for uploading the document??

> EDIT
>   my link for upload is something like this

```
https://sharepoint.asr.ith.itl.com/sites/SK/patchboard/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={CE897D7B-8DC4-4F9C-AF4D-D41DB89DA6D3}&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSKX%2Fpatchboard%2FDocuments%2FPatch%5Fautomation%5Fwork%5Farea
```

This link brings me to a page where in I need to browse the complete path to the file and then after giving the path I would be able to upload the document.

My file path is-

```
/abc/asc/roj/skx/skx_val/rsingh/Patch/Excel.xlsm
```

Now I want to concatenate this file path to my above url so that a path for direct upload can be formed.Direct Concatenation is not working as I think direct concatenation does not knows the meaning of browse option and may be that's while its unable to put the file path at its desired location.

Can somebody tell me how to resolve it.

Comment: You can try [urjoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) for creating URLs or use any of string formatting approaches(`%s`, `format()`, f-string)

Comment: Actually I am having a url that takes me directly to "upload page" where I need to browse through the file system using browse button to provide the path to the file that i want to upload. I am clueless about how to provide the link from upload to browse option that will then give the actual url that is uploading the file.-@Andersson

Comment: tried concatenating using format specifier also. Giving the same result. Actually the problem is there is an API function used _api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(\'' + folderUrl + '\')/Files/addas(url=\'' + fileName + '\',overwrite=true)'  and instead of giving its value the name of the function upto "serverrelativeurl" is taken in the link itself and part of function and its arguments after that  is at it is, which is ultimately not completing the url-@Andersson

Comment: Can you share exact desired output (URL you want to get)?

Comment: Exact I can not share because sharepoint is company's confidential but will show edited form in the Question itself-@Andersson

Comment: Edited the question. I hope it will help you-@Andersson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. Instead of giving the url link from the browser,I have given the base url for the sharepoint like-

https://sharepoint.asr.ith.itl.com

and then added path to the desired location in the sharepoint where I wanted to upload the file like-

```
sites/SK/patchboard/shared_documents/patch_work_area
```

This formed the complete link as-

```
https://sharepoint.asr.ith.itl.com/sites/SK/patchboard/shared_documents/patch_work_area
```

then I have used the command as-

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password --upload-file <filename> https://sharepoint.amr.ith.intel.com/sites/SK/patchboard/shared_documents/patch_work_area/<file_name to upload>
```

This had worked for me.